# Keras is adding dimension to shape

Tags: keras, tensorflow

When I create an InputLayer, a `None` dimension gets added. I don't know why this is.

```
    image_shape = ds_info.features['image'].shape
    input_shape = (ds_info.features['label'].num_classes, image_shape[0], image_shape[1], image_shape[2])

    print('input_shape: ', input_shape)
    
    ## Create the CNN
    # Create the input layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    print('input_layer: ', input_layer.shape)
```

### Results

```
input_shape:  (1623, 105, 105, 3)
input_layer:  (None, 1623, 105, 105, 3)
```

Comment: The None dimension is the batch dimension, indicating that any number of examples (e.g. 4, 8, 16 etc.) can be put into the network. See also [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54161/75157) answer.

Comment: Ok but this changes the shape of the model which results in error for me.